# How to add "this comment will also be posted to [a website]" under a facebook comment?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-comments

Noticed this  line "this comment will also be posted to [a website]" below the comment on a facebook page (check https://www.facebook.com/Scoopwhoop/ ).

How do I integrate this feature where in the comments posted on my facebook page are shown on the blog post of my wordpress website.

Comment: Comment Mirroring, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

Answer (score 0):

It's OK?
Look for mirroring comments. It will solve your problem.
Just activate it in the plugin and you're done!

Comment: It seems more like a comment. You should post it as a comment.